# Installing the Gracenote SDK (GNSDK) within XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gracenote

I am attempting to get the GNSDK framework working within XCode but I'm having some issues. I dragged the framework file from the example project into my project and adding a bridging header (since the rest of my project is in Swift). The bridging header consists of:

```
#import <GnSDKObjC/Gn.h>
```

However, XCode returns that this header file cannot be found. This is what my "frameworks" look like:

[Frameworks screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0JRi.png)

Note that adding or removing the .plist and .pch files does nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the framework in the "Link Binary With Libraries" dropdown? Click on your project name (1st item in your Project Navigator). You should be able to see them in the main window. You could try deleting it and adding from here.